# Add specific citation based on user selection with vba

Tags: vba, field, ms-word, citations

I am trying to create a userform where the user selects a year and a citation for a specific book is inserted based on that option. I have tried inserting a DOCVARIABLE (called "BookYear") field inside the text and then changing the variables value (to "Aus15") through VBA. The code below doesnt work but I think I'm on the right path

```
Sub Macro2()
    If myComboBox = 2015 Then
        ActiveDocument.Variable("BookYear").Value = "Aus15"
        ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

MyText = "Aus15"

Selection Example:
''çode to select bookmark
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _

Type:=wdFieldCitation, Text:=MyText